# How can I verify my Time Machine password?

Tags: time-machine

Since I've been using for Time Machine for a long time with several machines that I no longer have, I would like to do some cleanup on my password manager but I don't want to erase my current Time Machine password by mistake. How can I test my time machine password in some simple way? I'm assuming I can do it from the recovery screen but that would be pretty painful if I have to try out several passwords, most of which are pretty long. Any way I can test it from OSX running normally on my laptop?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you first **copy the backup** to another location (to avoid impacting the original) and then unmount and remount it?  It should ask for your password to remount.  You **definitely** want to do this on a copy because giving the wrong password will prevent you from getting at those files again.  Yes, it can be time-consuming if you're wrong but it would help if you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is:

- backup every of these passwords.
- remove them one-by-one and mount and unmount your current Time Machine hard drive.
- Once you are prompted for a password to decrypt the Time Machine backup, it means that you removed the only password you needed.

Comment: Thank you, that got me to the password I wanted. I'm still going to do a recovery into another disk just to be absolutely sure.

Comment: You are welcome :)